How to ignore Error found when loading /home/(username)/.profile
I have some command in .profile that can fail or succeed, I don't care about the error, if it failed just ignore it. However, even if I put it in an if block and redirect its output to /dev/null, there's still an error shown up. I also tried wrap around that command with set +e and set -e but doesn't work.
I don't want to remove the command.
if command > /dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  :
else
  :
fi


Your if conditional is unneeded you could just run command > /dev/null 2>&1 however that only suppresses the errors coming to the terminal, this error is clearly going to a GUI.  You will have to find a way to suppress the error either with some command line arguments for the command, or find a way to check if the config is already loaded before attempting to run the command.

Please [edit] your question and show more details. Does the "some command" print messages to stdout or stderr that end up as part of the text in the error message window?
Is the "some command" the last command in .profile? Does command || true help?

(1) What is the command that does this?  (2) Why do you not want to remove it?  Is it accomplishing something (in spite of the fact that it reports a problem)?  (3) Or are you saying that you need to keep it because it sometimes succeeds?  Can you characterize the cases when it succeeds?  (4) Does this happen when you log in?  Are you doing . .profile?   (5) What happens if you prefix the command with DISPLAY=?

Why don't you find out the real error is, and fix it ?

I am using nitrogen --restore to load desktop background. Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it fails. I also have other commands might need network access and can fail as well. So I think about ignoring those errors as a quick and dirty solution.

I found that error message didn't come from the command I thought. The actual command causing problem didn't exit with error code. However, it logged a message to stderr.
So to ignore any error, we need to redirect command errors to or /dev/null (or a log file for debugging).
